# Handling user input in custom Ansible network module

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to develop a set of Ansible network modules for a particular storage device. I have this Pytohn code:

```py
from ansible.module_utils.connection import Connection
def run_commands(module, command, prompt=None, answer=None): 
    connection = Connection(module._socket_path) 
    out = connection.send_command(command=command, prompt=prompt, answer=answer)
```

It works for a non-interactive command (without any prompt\answer) and doesn't work if the command waits for an user input (for example, manually entering a password).
I've tried to set any combination of prompt\answer to no avail:

`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 30 secs.\nSee the timeout setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide.", "rc": -32603}`

Below are examples of commands.
Non-interactive command (input-response) that works with connection.send_command():

```
sysadmin@toad# user show list
User list from node "localhost".
Name       Uid   Role    Last Login From   Last Login Time            Status    Disable Date
--------   ---   -----   ---------------   ------------------------   -------   ------------
sysadmin   100   admin   192.168.31.44     Mon Oct 17 04:20:44 2022   enabled   never
testuser   500   user    <unknown>         never                      enabled   never
username   501   user    <unknown>         never                      locked    never
--------   ---   -----   ---------------   ------------------------   -------   ------------
3 users found.
```

Interactive command (input-prompt-answer-prompt2-answer2-response) that doesn't work with my code:

```
sysadmin@toad# user change password testuser
    Enter new password:
    Re-enter new password:
Passwords matched.
```